# Deepstream unable to use tee and use splitmuxsink to save video

Tags: python, gstreamer, deepstream.io, nvidia-deepstream

unable to use tee and use splitmuxsink to save video ,below is the code and i get linking error while running the below snippet.
im using tee to have 2-sinks ( video save and RTSP streaming)

> ```
> nvvidconv_c = "convertor_%u" %index
> print("Creating nvvidconv \n ")
> nvvidconv = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvideoconvert", nvvidconv_c)
> if not nvvidconv:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create nvvidconv %u\n", i)
>
> caps_c = "caps1_%u" %index
> caps1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", caps_c)
> caps1.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420"))
>
>
> # Make the encoder
> encoder_c = "encoder1_%u" %index
> print("Creating H264 Encoder")
> encoder1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2h264enc", encoder_c)
> if not encoder1:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create encoder")
>
> encoder1.set_property('bitrate', bitrate)
>
>
> caps_c = "cap2s_%u" %index
> caps2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", caps_c)
> # caps1.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=I420"))
> caps2.set_property("caps", Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw, format=I420"))
>
> encoder_c = "encoder2_%u" %index
> print("Creating H264 Encoder")
> # encoder2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2h264enc", encoder_c)
> encoder2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc", encoder_c)
> if not encoder2:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create encoder")
>
> encoder2.set_property('bitrate', bitrate)
>
>
>
>
>
> # Make the payload-encode video into RTP packets
> rtppay_c = "rtppay_%u" %index
> rtppay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264pay", rtppay_c)
> print("Creating H264 rtppay")
> if not rtppay:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create rtppay")
>
> # Make the UDP sink
> updsink_port_num = udp_sink_port_num
> updsink_port_num += index
> print("\n updsink_port_num = %u", updsink_port_num)
> udpsink_c = "udpsink_%u" %index
> sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("udpsink", udpsink_c)
> if not sink:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create udpsink")
>
> sink.set_property('host', '224.224.255.255')
> sink.set_property('port', updsink_port_num)
> sink.set_property('async', False)
> sink.set_property('sync', 1)
>
> sink.set_property("qos",0)
>
> tee=Gst.ElementFactory.make("tee", "nvsink-tee")
> if not tee:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create tee \n")
> tee_msg_pad=tee.get_request_pad('src_%u')
> tee_render_pad=tee.get_request_pad("src_%u")
>
> if not tee_msg_pad or not tee_render_pad:
>     sys.stderr.write("Unable to get request pads\n")
>
> queue1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "nvtee-que1")
> if not queue1:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create queue1 \n")
>
> queue2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "nvtee-que2")
> if not queue2:
>     sys.stderr.write(" Unable to create queue2 \n")
>
>
>
>
> splitmuxsink_c = "splitmuxsink_%u" %index
> print("Creating splitmuxsink \n ")
> splitmuxsink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("splitmuxsink", splitmuxsink_c)
> # splitmuxsink.set_property('muxer', Gst.ElementFactory.make('matroskamux'))
>
> splitmuxsink.set_property('muxer', Gst.ElementFactory.make('qtmux'))
> splitmuxsink.set_property('location', '/home/ubuntu/sriharsha/videos/testing/segment_%09d.mkv')
> splitmuxsink.set_property('max-size-time', 10000000000) #10s segments
>
>
> sink_pad = queue1.get_static_pad("sink")
> tee_msg_pad = tee.get_request_pad('src_%u')
> tee_render_pad = tee.get_request_pad("src_%u")
> if not tee_msg_pad or not tee_render_pad:
>     sys.stderr.write("Unable to get request pads\n")
> tee_msg_pad.link(sink_pad)
> sink_pad = queue2.get_static_pad("sink")
> tee_render_pad.link(sink_pad)
> try:    
>     Gst.Bin.add(nbin, queue, nvvidconv_pre, nvosd, nvvidconv, caps1, encoder1, caps2, encoder2, queue1, queue2 ,tee,  splitmuxsink,
> ```
>
> rtppay, sink)
> except Exception as e:
> print("error in gst bin add", e)
>
> ```
> #link 
> queue.link(nvvidconv_pre)
>
> nvvidconv_pre.link(nvosd)
> nvosd.link(nvvidconv)
> nvvidconv.link(tee)
>
> queue2.link(caps2)
> caps2.link(encoder2)
> encoder2.link(encoder2)
> encoder2.link(splitmuxsink)
>
> queue1.link(caps1)
> caps1.link(encoder1)
> encoder1.link(rtppay)
> rtppay.link(sink)
>
>
>
>
>
> #ghostpad
> pad = queue.get_static_pad("sink")
> ghost_pad = Gst.GhostPad.new("sink", pad)
> nbin.add_pad(ghost_pad)
> ```

and i get the below error :

> Error: gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1):
> gstqueue.c(988): gst_queue_handle_sink_event ():
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstBin:sink-bin-00/GstQueue:queue_sink_0:
> streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for your case, but after tee splitmuxsink might need to have `async-handling` property enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SeB. Setting `async-handling=true` fixed a similar issue for me. However I also used factories and had `async-finalize=true` enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).